# cloudwatch event trigger cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am having some trouble writing the cloudformation script for cloudwatch event trigger to kick off my lambda script, I know I can do it through the console but my requirement is that I need to provision everything in cloudformation. I followed the documentation and it still haven't worked for me and I kept getting the error:

> Template contains errors.: Invalid template property or properties
>   [rPermissionForEventsToInvokeLambda, rLambdaScheduledRule]

can someone point out what is the issue with this part of my cloudformation script? I followed the document almost to the letter and still having error, even the example in the documentation have the same error when I tried to validate it. my cloudformation code is below, any help is appreciated!

```
rLambdaScheduledRule:
  Type: AWS::Events::Rule
  Properties:
    ScheduleExpression: rate(1 hour)
    State: ENABLED
    Targets:
      Ref: 
        Fn::ImportValue:
          Fn::Sub: rUploadLambda
    Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
rPermissionForEventsToInvokeLambda: 
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties: 
    FunctionName: 
      Ref: 
        Fn::ImportValue:
        Fn::Sub: rUploadLambda
    Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
    Principal: events.amazonaws.com
    SourceArn: 
      Fn::GetAtt: 
        - rLambdaScheduledRule
        - Arn
```

Comment: Is this your complete cloudformation template? Since it is complaining about rLambdaScheduledRule and rPermissionForEventsToInvokeLambda, maybe they are not put under 'Resources' ? Just a guess...

Answer (score 4):

1) You must export the *Lambda function ARN* in the CloudFormation template in which you create the lambda function. You need to pass the *Lambda function ARN*  as input to the cloudwatch event (The `AWS::Events::Rule` *Targets* attribute requires a resource ARN).

See a sample script below:

```
Resources:
  # Create Controlled Lambda Function
  myLambda:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties: 
      Code:
        S3Bucket: "lambda-bucket"
        S3Key: "myhandler.zip"
      Description: "Lambda handler"
      FunctionName: "myhandler"
      Handler: myhandler.myhandler
      MemorySize: 128
      Role: "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/myLambdaExecutionRole-NC7FA7TUSZ5B"
      Runtime: "python3.6"
      Timeout: 10

# Output of the cf template
Outputs:
  myLambdaArn:
    Description: Arn of the my_lambda_function
    Value: !GetAtt myLambda.Arn
    Export: 
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-LambdaArn"
```

2) When you create the *CloudWatch Event*, you need to pass the ***ARN*** of the lambda function created in Step1 as the *Target*.

See a sample script below:

```
Resources:
  # Cloudwatch event to trigger lambda periodically
  rLambdaScheduledRule:
    Type: "AWS::Events::Rule"
    Properties: 
      Description: "CloudWatch Event to trigger lambda fn"
      ScheduleExpression: "rate(1 hour)"
      State: "ENABLED"
      Targets:
        - 
          Arn: 
            Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub "${NetworkStackName}-LambdaArn"
          Id: "targetevent_v1"

  PermissionForEventsToInvokeLambda: 
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties: 
      FunctionName: 
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub "${NetworkStackName}-LambdaArn"
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Principal: "events.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: 
        Fn::GetAtt: 
          - rLambdaScheduledRule
          - Arn
```

The value of `${NetworkStackName}` should be the *StackName* from Step1.
Some of the issues you need to correct in your template:

- correct the **Targets** property of resource `rLambdaScheduledRule`.
- remove **Action** property from resource `rLambdaScheduledRule`.
- correct the **FunctionName** property of resource `rPermissionForEventsToInvokeLambda`.

Keeping above sample as reference, correct your template and try again.